# Google Fusion Tables and SMS notifiaction

Tags: android, google-maps, sms, kml, google-fusion-tables

I have the following case: Notify  (txt /sms) the recipient of a package when the courier (who has a mobile device, access to internet) is within 30min  from the recipient. / using Google Fusion tables/.

Is this possible and could someone draw, in general, the process and schema? I don't need a code, just would like to understand how the elements are connected. Links to guides/articles for Google Fusion tables can be connected with SMS notification also could be useful.
Thank you.

Comment: What kind of data do you want to store in Fusion Tables? I can't see how this is connected to Fusion Tables.

Comment: Well...that's what I'm trying to understand. I assume the location of the courier will be stored in Fusion Tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure if I understand your requirements, but maybe something like that could work.

The components you need:

1. A software on the couriers mobile to track his position. This could be done automatically or via an explicit action of the courier (e.g. [newer browsers allow to get the geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation)).
2. The address of your recipients, this would make sense to store in Fusion Tables. Just [tell Fusion Tables to geocode the addresses of your customers](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/1012281).
3. A service to determine "30min from recipient", maybe this could be done using [Google Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). Otherwise you could define a distance (like 20km away) rather than a time, which makes it much easier to implement
4. You need a service to send text/sms

With such a setup you could regularly use the couriers position in a [spatial query](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select) on your customers data in Fusion Tables. This would answer a question like: *Is there a customer in 20km distance of the courier?*

If this is the case, you could trigger your text / sms service to notify your customers.

Comment: Thank you Odi -that's what I'm looking for. I'm just missing the last point -maybe because I can't imagine how such system works and how it can be connected with GFT but at this stage that's enough.